# WSO2 Identity Server - cant get SAML token from STS

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, rampart

With much trouble, I've gotten a sample console application working up to the point of sending a request to the Identity server STS to get a security token..

Here's the exception that Identity server reports:

```
[2013-03-15 14:31:04,563] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler} -  Error occuerd while populating claim
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler.loadClaims(AttributeCallbackHandler.java:136)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.provider.AttributeCallbackHandler.handle(AttributeCallbackHandler.java:68)
        at org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.createAttributeAssertion(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:544)
        at org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.createHoKAssertion(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:419)
        at org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.issue(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:173)
        at org.apache.rahas.TokenRequestDispatcher.handle(TokenRequestDispatcher.java:69)
        at org.apache.rahas.STSMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(STSMessageReceiver.java:57)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
org.apache.rahas.TrustException: Error in creating a SAMLToken using Opensaml library
        at org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.createAttributeAssertion(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:585)
        at org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.createHoKAssertion(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:419)
        at org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.issue(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:173)
        at org.apache.rahas.TokenRequestDispatcher.handle(TokenRequestDispatcher.java:69)
        at org.apache.rahas.STSMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(STSMessageReceiver.java:57)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.opensaml.MalformedException: AttributeStatement is invalid, requires at least one attribute
        at org.opensaml.SAMLAttributeStatement.checkValidity(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLObject.toDOM(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLSubjectStatement.toDOM(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLAttributeStatement.toDOM(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLAssertion.toDOM(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLObject.toDOM(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLSignedObject.toDOM(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLObject.toDOM(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLSignedObject.sign(Unknown Source)
        at org.opensaml.SAMLSignedObject.sign(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.createAttributeAssertion(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:581)
        ... 39 more
```

From all the documentation, I've followed all the steps to secure the STS service and configure it correctly.  Seems like something is not configured to know which claims to send back.

The client code is from the Identity server documentation for the 4.1.0 release for '[Security Token Server](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/Security+Token+Service+with+WSO2+Identity+Server)'

Can anyone help?

Comment: I feel there's something wrong with the client application you are using. Probably the request sent to STS doesn't specify what claims are required (i.e. missing claim element). Is it possible to attach the client code?

Comment: Added link to the client code I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you gotta send at least 1 claim, i sugest to do it this way:

```
private static OMElement getRSTTemplate() throws Exception {
        OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
        OMElement elem = fac.createOMElement(Constants.RST_TEMPLATE);
        TrustUtil.createTokenTypeElement(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, elem)
                .setText(XML.SAML_NS);
        TrustUtil.createKeyTypeElement(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, elem,
                RahasConstants.KEY_TYPE_SYMM_KEY);
        TrustUtil.createKeySizeElement(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, elem, 256);
        TrustUtil.createClaims(RahasConstants.VERSION_05_02, elem,"http://wso2.org");
        addClaimType(elem,"http://wso2.org/claims/givenname");
        return elem;
       }

       private static void addClaimType(OMElement parent,String uri) {
        OMElement element = null;
        element = parent.getOMFactory().createOMElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity", "ClaimType", "wsid"),
                      parent);
        element.addAttribute( parent.getOMFactory().createOMAttribute("Uri",null,uri));
       }
```